# Importing specific parts of an array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, fetch

So I've been working on this project. I'm a very beginner, I have spent about 30 hours so far watching videos and reading and only got 30 lines written. Total brainfreeze.
It's suposed to be a homepage showing FN consistency goals and then clickable titels to show more detailed parts. No more no less complicated. Just the text, CSS isn't a problem at all.

With this, I've managed to console-log the titles, although all messed up in an array.
Showing like:

```
[{"code":"1","title":"End poverty in all its forms everywhere","description":"Goal 1 calls for an end to poverty in all its manifestations, including extreme poverty, over the next 15 years. All people everywhere, including the poorest and most vulnerable, should enjoy a basic standard of living and social protection benefits.","url":"/v1/sdg/Goal/1"},
{"code":"2","title": '...'}]
```

and on and on.
Can anyone please help me.

```
function getGoalList(GoalList) {
    fetch(URL_API)
    .then( res => {
        return res.json()
    })
    .catch(error = console.log('wrong'))
    console.log(URL_API)
}

function fetchData() {
    fetch("https://unstats.un.org/SDGAPI/v1/sdg/Goal/List?uncludechildren=true")
    .then(response => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data)
        document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = `<h1> ${data} </h1> `
        console.log("test test " + JSON.stringify(data))
        for (var i =0; i < data.length; i++){


        }
    })
}
fetchData();
```

---

please!

Comment: it's not clear to me what problem you're having

Comment: you made a typo in query parameter of the fetch data url "uncludechildren" instead of "includechildren"

Comment: thats just a very minor problem. still doesnt print without the id and the titel..

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please format your example response part using {} symbol in edit mode to simplify reading. What is getGoalList used for, not called from fetchData at least. Also, is it the title and/or description you want to get from each goal (17 in total)?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to set your `div`'s `innerHTML` to an array of objects here:

```
document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = `<h1> ${data} </h1> `
```

That is not possible!

You should instead map through that array and do something with each element. In the following example I'm just logging the title:

```
data.map(element=> console.log(element.title))
```

Hope that solves the problem.

Comment: It did, TYVM! I got the "goals/titels" sorted nice in the console, now i just have to print them on the html.. can you help me?

as i said, im a total beginner, spent just as many hour as rows written, if not more, i just cant get over that treshhold and i got a deadline tomorrow

Comment: If you want to create an h1 element for each title:
data.map(element=> {
let el = document.createElement(h1);
el.innerHTML = element.title;
body.appendChild(el);
})

Answer (score 0):

The json data you have fetched from the website is basically and array of javascript object containing the title, code, decription, uri.

```
  {
    "code": "1",
    "title": "title you want",
    "description": "description you want",
    "uri": "/v1/sdg/Goal/1"
  }
```

To access these properties, you can call the object (say `obj`) and call `obj.title`,`obj.code` etc.

To access all the titles and descriptions in the array, you can loop over every object in the array and retrieve the data you need for you projects.

I've included an example using the code you have provided , hopefully that can help you in your project

```js
function getGoalList(GoalList) {
    fetch(URL_API)
    .then( res => {
        return res.json()
    })
    .catch(error = console.log('wrong'))
    console.log(URL_API)
}

function fetchData() {
    fetch("https://unstats.un.org/SDGAPI/v1/sdg/Goal/List?uncludechildren=true")
    .then(response => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
        console.log("an example of the json object")
        console.log(data[0]) // <-- a json object in the array
        console.log("accessing properties of the object")
        console.log(data[0].title) // <-- accessing the title
        console.log(data[0].description) // <-- similarly accessing the description
        console.log("using loop to iterate and print out all the properties of the object array!")
        for (var i =0; i < data.length; i++){
          console.log(data[i].title)
          console.log(data[i].description)

        }
        
    })
}
fetchData();
```